# Python parallel-ssh run_command does not timeout when using pssh.clients

Tags: python, parallel-ssh

I have the following code:

```
from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient
#-------------------------------------------------

hosts = [ IP1, IP2, ... IPn]
host_config = { dict containing userid & passwd for each host }

clients = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, host_config=host_config,
                           num_retries=1, timeout=3)

output = clients.run_command("ls", stop_on_errors=False, timeout=3)
print output
```

If my hosts have all valid IPs, then I get "output".  However, if even one of the IPs is invalid (non-existing host),  then the run_command hangs forever.  Even tried using "use_pty=True" argument to run_command.

Strange thing is that if I use the deprecated method **pssh_client** instead of **clients** like follows:

```
from pssh.pssh_client import ParallelSSHClient
```

it times-out as expected. Either there is a bug introduced with the new way of importing or there is some new way to specify timeout properly.  I would prefer to use the recommended way instead of the deprecated way.  But recommended way is not working for me. Anyone know if I am doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Report it as a bug on the project's bug tracker: https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh/issues

Comment: They have accepted this as a valid bug.  Thanks John for the link for posting the bug.

Comment: Please post a link to the bug here, perhaps in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has been confirmed as a bug on the ParallelSSH's github site.  Hence, this issue is closed. Issue was listed at:

https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh/issues/133